# Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name LocalStrings, locale en_US

Tags: java, servlets, locale

I know this question has been asked before many times, but after reading through all of them, I unfortunately couldn't find an answer that applied to me. The reason I say that is because my "base name" is coming up as "LocalStrings" and I'm not exactly sure why. Here is what my web.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Backend</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.backend.BackendServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestKody</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.backend.TestKody</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestKody</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestKody</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Backend</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/backend</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I can get to the "Backend" servlet fine, but whenever I try to get to "TestKody" it comes up with the error "Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name LocalStrings, locale en_US." Again I apologize for asking a question that has been asked before, but again I couldn't find an answer that pointed me in the right direction!

EDIT:

Here are pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to fetch/load your resource file?

Comment: @Abdelhak I apologize, but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Abdelhak sorry, I'm freshly new to eclipse/java! I created a web application project from google's plugin. I didn't create a .properties file myself, but there are two there (though I don't know if they are what you're looking for). I'm going to upload a picture of both of them and the file structure so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing the `servlet-api` jar,f you're using maven add this dependency in your project:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

If not you can add the jar in your classpath from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxservletjar.htm).

Comment: I downloaded the jar, put it in my lib folder, went to Project > Properties > Java Build path > Add JARs and selected that jar but it still isn't working. Is there anything else I'm missing?